# How to differentiate object created using {} vs object created using new keyword

Tags: javascript

There are 2 ways to create object

1. Direct

   var x={};
2. Using the new keyword i.e using constructor function.

   var x=new Object(); 
   //or
   var x=new Date(); //using constructor function.

Is there any way to determine how that object is created?

Comment: Why would you need to know this?

Comment: As such there is no any provision in javascript as what I know... if you explain your scenario there could be another way to solve your problem !!..

Comment: I was asked same in some interview

Comment: @ankurkushwaha Then answer is NO, if you have explained right what Interviewer asked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, in JavaScript, we **don't care** how an object was created. We normally just assume that if the object walks like a duck and talks like a duck, it's a duck. (This is called "duck typing.") And that turns out to be just as well, because we *can't* know how an object was created.

There are really two questions here:

1. How can you tell whether an object was created with an object initializer (`{}`) or `new Object`, and
2. How can you tell whether an object was created with one of those or some other constructor function (like `Date`).

The answer to Question 1 is: You can't. There is no difference, at all, in the resulting object, so you can't tell how it was created.

The answer to Question 2 is more complicated:

You can't know, for certain, that an object was created with a given constructor. JavaScript is too powerful, giving you too much control over the object, for it to be possible to be sure.

All you can know is what the object's prototype chain tells you, from which you can *infer* how it was constructed, but the inference could be incorrect.

Let's take your

```
var x = new Date();
```

example. To do that inference, you can use at least three tools:

1. `instanceof`: E.g., `if (x instanceof Date)`. `instanceof` is an operator accepting an object and a function. It checks the object's prototype chain to see if the object the function's `prototype` property refers to is anywhere in the chain. If so, `instanceof`'s result is `true`; if not, it's `false`. So if the object is created with `new Date` (or `new Foo` if `Foo` derives from `Date`), `x instanceof Date` will be true.

   But again, JavaScript is really powerful, and you can fool it. For instance:

   ```js
   var x = Object.create(Date.prototype);
   console.log(x instanceof Date); // true
   ```

   We didn't use `new Date` to create that object, but we can't tell that we didn't. (And in this particular case, `x` won't work correctly as a `Date`, because `Date` objects have a special internal slot that normal objects don't have. Many of the `Date.prototype` functions will fail on the above. But that's `Date`-specific.)
2. The `constructor` property. By default, the `prototype` property on a function has a property, `constructor`, that points back to the function. E.g., `Date.prototype.constructor === Date` is `true` in the normal case. Since objects created with a constructor get that object as their prototype, you can use `constructor` to see what constructor (if any) is associated with that object: `if (x.constructor === Date)` will be `true` for something created with `new Date` (in the normal case).

   But again, we can fool that check:

   ```js
   var x = Object.create({constructor: Date});
   console.log(x.constructor === Date); // true
   ```
3. `getPrototypeOf` and related: You can check the prototype chain of an object directly (rather than just through `instanceof`). But this has the same vulnerability that `instanceof` has: We can fool it by creating the object with `Object.create` (or before `Object.create` was in the language, using custom constructor function).

`instanceof` has the advantage that it checks the entire hierarchy, and doesn't rely on `constructor`; in hierarchies created with ES5 and earlier (e.g., before ES2015's `class`), people frequently failed to set `constructor`correctly.

So again, fundamentally, we don't care how an object was created; and that's just as well, because we can't know, for sure, how it was created.

Comment: right, but its not only date, it can be Blob, it can be any custom constructor function. How can i create a generic check

Comment: @ankurkushwaha: Well, `instanceof` and `constructor` **are** generic checks. I've also updated a bit to expand on this. Basically, in JavaScript, we don't care how an object was created.

Answer (score 2):

You can't differentiate creation of plain object since for javascript this is exactly the same thing.

```
var o1 = {};
var o2 = new Object();
```